# kfd: error getting iommu info

Tags: linux, boot

I got this error during boot process.

```
[15.757121] kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
[15.757182] kfd kfd: Error initializing iommuv2 for device (1002:1318)
[15.757245] Creating topology SYSFS entries
[15.757376] kfd kfd: device (1002:1318) NOT added due to errors
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Bad BIOS UEFI tables are a common problem, which yield a non funtional iommu.

If on X86 or AMD64 try:

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`:

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=pt"
```

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.

---

In many cases the "pass through" function of the kernel will provide iommu funtionality also the **BIOS** is **foobar**. The HSA software stack will run on a system with a working iommu funtionality without tiggering the iommu error message.

Comment: I had `iommu=soft` and changed it to `=pt` [pass-through] and now my IOMMU appears to be working without giving errors in dmesg output. Cheers. I'm on AMD64 (A8-7600 Kaveri).

Comment: I my case DELL 5575 "Ryzen 5 2500U" (clevo board) `ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2` was helpful.

Comment: @Jan `ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2` helped also in my case (Matebook D14 AMD 2500U)

Comment: Where do you get the numbers [4] [5] and 00:14.0  from  ?

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275207) from a Google Search:

UEFI boot was a red herring. The real problem was that you need a `kfd.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. The file must say:

```
KERNEL=="kfd", GROUP="video", MODE="0660"
```

You may also need to set proper selinux policy

```
restorecon /etc/udev/rules.d/kfd.rules
```

Installing mainline 3.19 in Ubuntu 14.10 created this file during package installation (we think?), but Ubuntu 15.04 does not create this file by default. You must do it by hand. Then the HSA software stack works!

Problem solved.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I have this file, but also the symptoms in the OP. This doesn't appear to fix things. I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.2 now, kernel 5.0.0-15-generic.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error (between others) using a linux embedded **udoo bolt** device that was using a cloned HD (using `dd`) from another identical device.

The problem was solved updating disks information on `/etc/fstab` with the correct `UUID`.

Using `blkid` / `fdisk -l` on the new device the **UUID** of all disks can be found and used to update `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error following an AMD GPU error, add `amd_iommu=on` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` as well.