# How can I boot to console mode on a Debian Live USB?

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I've created a Debian Live USB with persistence on Windows using Rufus.
When I boot to it, I see errors related to [ACPI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting) and [kdf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263901/kfd-error-getting-iommu-info).

I'd like to make the changes suggested in the links but I don't see any Advanced options in the GRUB menu to access console mode.

I've tried adding `3` to the end of the "linux" line, as suggested [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/how-to-boot-to-console-text-mode-in.html) but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. I added the `1` but I cannot see any discernible difference. I also deleted `quiet` and I can see the full message log, but only the last page. I did run `dmesg` and send the output to a text file, but when I logged back into Windows I couldn't see it.

Comment: Unfortunately no, as I see the `ACPI` and `kdf` errors (above), that I'm trying to resolve. Some background: I'm trying a Live Debian USB to familiarize myself before switching to Linux.

This is the screen I see https://www.debian.wayoflinux.com/user/pages/03.installing/01.get-debian/03.try-a-live-cd/start-Live-CD.png (ignore the kernel version).

From there I can go into the grub menu, but what I'm really after is console mode.
Thanks

Comment: i do not see any ACPI and kdf errors posted by you ... all you did was to post links to some other posts

Comment: Apologies. I meant I can press `e` and edit the parameters. But I cannot access the console/terminal to edit `/etc/default/grub`. Or to put it another way, I can address the first error message by adding `acpi=off` to the end of the kernel line. However, I don't see any line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` in order to add `"iommu=pt"`.

Comment: The errors are `[Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table` and `kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?` in the second link. Thanks.

Comment: try this ... see the second picture here https://serverfault.com/questions/482079/debian-boot-to-single-user-mode .... the line that starts with `linux` and ends with `quiet`  ... find a similar line in the grub menu entry edit .... remove the word `quiet` ... add `1 acpi=off iommu=pt`

Comment: Hi, I tried but the error persists:     `kdf kdf: allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
kdf kdf: error getting iommu info. is the iommu emabled?  
kdf kdf: Error initializing iommuv2
kdf kdf: device 1002:15dd NOT added due to errors`. It seems it's a common error with AMD machines, but I expected `iommu=pt` to fix it. Thanks for your help anyway.