# Debian boot error: AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter

Tags: debian, amd, iommu

I'm booting a stable live Debian USB (with persistence) on a Windows 10 laptop with an AMD Ryzen 5 2500U processor. I should add that I've tried both the official and non-free Debian versions.

The following error is displayed:

```
AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
kfd kfd: Failed to resume IOMMU for device 1002:15dd
kfd kfd: device 1002:15dd NOT added due to errors
```

I've tried the following in the grub boot menu parameters:

`ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2` per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413006 (second comment) and https://superuser.com/a/1473785

`amd_iommu=on ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2` per https://askubuntu.com/a/1050026

I also tried `iommu=off` but the issue persists.

Being a laptop, the BIOS options are fairly basic, but for what it's worth, virtualization is enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Does the BIOS have a separate setting for IOMMU? Try using `iommu=pt` instead of `iommu=off`.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201753 It's old and no one seems to care about it :/

Comment: @ajgringo619 thanks for the suggestion. I tried both that and amd_iommu=pt but no luck.
Adrien Clerc thanks for that. I guess I'll have to wait for a fix, if any.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. I asked about a separate setting in the BIOS because my x470 board has it, whereas my previous board did not.

Comment: Hi, no there isn't a separate IOMMU setting in BIOS. It's fairly basic/limited and not what you'd get on a desktop board. Virtualization is enabled, though.

Comment: Update: there seems to be some movement on the bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201753