# How can enable iommu in AMD CPU during boot?

Tags: boot, amd, iommu

Motherboard info:

```
sudo dmidecode -t  baseboard | grep -B 1  Product   
Manufacturer: Colorful Technology And Development Co.,LTD
Product Name: BATTLE-AX B450M-HD
```

CPU info:

```
sudo dmidecode -t  processor | grep Version   
Version: AMD Athlon 3000G with Radeon Vega Graphics
```

OS info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have enabled SVM in the bios setting,and set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX according to:
[kfd: error getting iommu info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263901/kfd-error-getting-iommu-info)

```
grep  'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX'  /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet amd_iommu=on iommu=pt"
```

Reboot,check booting info on iommu:

```
sudo dmesg | grep  "error"
[    4.056168] kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
[    4.056221] kfd kfd: device 1002:15d8 NOT added due to errors
```

Maybe we can't enable it on AMD CPU because it is not a bug?

```
sudo dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU
[    1.191400] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system - This is not a bug.
```

I have enabled the SVM mode in my motherboard's BIOS,and `sudo update-grub`,the iommu issue remains after reboot.

[image]

Comment: After modifying /etc/default/grub you want to run 'sudo update-grub' so the changes can take effect.

Comment: have you enabled iommu in the bios

Comment: note: `AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system` is a message you'd always get on an intel platform, since intel wouldn't do AMP IOMMUv2

Answer (score 0):

IOMMU is set by your BIOS. If BIOS doesn't enable this feature, it can't be used.